# Почему надо писать "дОлина"?

Tags: орфография, проверочные-слова

Почему слово "долина" пишется через О, если проверочное слово "даль"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверочное слово у "долины" не "даль", а "дол" - естественная природная низменность, овраг

Answer (score 1):

"Дол" во многих славянских языках означает ещё и "низ", так же как "гора" означает "верх".

Напр., по-сербски и по-чешски "доле" означает "вниз", а "горе", "нагору" - вверх (здесь звук "г" гортанный, как на Украине, а не взрывной, как в центральной России).

Долина - то, что внизу, в противоположность горе, которая вверху.

Эти вещи часто встречаются рядом, как противопоставления. Помните песню про освоение целины: "Родины просторы, горы и долины, ..."?

В русском изначальный смысл из слова "дол" ушёл, остался только в устойчивых выражениях типа "стоял потупя очи долу". Но если помнить, откуда что произошло, правописанию поможет

Answer (score 0):

Дол — это естественная природная низменность, овраг.

Answer (score 0):

Долина - от слова дол, долгий....Даль, отдаленный - имеет другое смысловое значение.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "долина" имеет прямую смысловую связь с "долом" — низким равнинным местом, располагающимся между высокими горами или холмами.
[Источник](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/proverochnoe-slovo-k-slovu-dolina.html)

Comment: Что нового ваш ответ добавил к уже приведённым ответам?

Comment: @AK *Что нового ваш ответ добавил к уже приведённым ответам?* здесь нет права первородства. Оценивайте вопрос по критериям лучше он или хуже и имеющихся - и насколько вообще правилен. А кто первый сказал "мяу" - это не столь критично.

Comment: @behemothus Посмотрите на три ответа. В 2012 году, в 2013 и 2014 году три ответа про "дол". Видимо, этого оказалось мало - и нужно было ещё один такой же добавить, чуть ли не слово-в-слово. Если вы считаете это нормальным или видите в этом какой-то смысл -- поясните мне, я реально не понимаю.

Comment: @AK Да хоть тридцать три. Он мог не читать (не обязан). Мог и вправду решить, "что мало". Мог счесть, что его ответ точнее, формулировка удачнее. Скорее всего - первое, но без разницы.  Это право пользователя давать любые ответы на любые вопросы. И если ответ сам по себе не содержит заведомо ошибочных сведений, антинаучных положений или еще чего-то подобного, то пусть болтается, удалять не надо. Если он совсем плох - заминусуйте, но объясните, в чем он ошибается по сути. А не потому, что ответ уже дан.